# Subversion server log shows a checkout time discrepancy

Tags: svn

Some of our automation has been overloading svn. While trolling through the logs, we noticed something weird (you'll have to scroll to the right). The same folder is being checked out repeatedly but svn says it sometimes takes 20 minutes and sometimes takes 40 seconds.

Our automation on the 40 second machines keeps track as well and says the checkout's taking about 20 minutes. What is going on? You'll notice the bytes value is also much smaller for the 40 second machines. Server and clients are running Windows 2008 R2.

```
[12/Jun/2015:07:26:40 -0000] user 10.80.1.71 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98698 (Bytes:788205202 Seconds:904)
[12/Jun/2015:07:40:39 -0000] user 10.80.1.96 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98698 (Bytes:788205202 Seconds:996)
[12/Jun/2015:07:47:19 -0000] user 10.80.1.14 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98698 (Bytes:788205202 Seconds:780)
[12/Jun/2015:07:44:12 -0000] user 10.80.1.73 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98698 (Bytes:788205202 Seconds:1000)
[12/Jun/2015:08:11:43 -0000] user 10.80.2.72 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98701 (Bytes:16239530 Seconds:40)
[12/Jun/2015:08:11:54 -0000] user 10.80.2.64 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98701 (Bytes:16239530 Seconds:39)
[12/Jun/2015:08:11:53 -0000] user 10.80.2.67 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98701 (Bytes:16239530 Seconds:40)
[12/Jun/2015:08:07:01 -0000] user 10.80.2.19 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98701 (Bytes:788205202 Seconds:1041)
[12/Jun/2015:08:08:51 -0000] user 10.80.2.18 repo:Dev checkout-or-export /branches/Dev/QA r98701 (Bytes:788205202 Seconds:1123)
```

It's especially weird because the 40 second machines are all clones of each other and the 20 minute machines are different VM templates. They all are running svn 1.8.10 so no problems there. Any insight is appreciated.

I watched a checkout on one of the 40 second machines and it actually took 20 minutes. I'm not sure what's going on and it'd be cool to find out so I'll leave this question open but there appears to be no actual difference.

Comment: What operating system server and clients are running? Do you  have any errors logged on server-side?

Comment: @IvanZhakov We are running Windows 2008 R2 and no errors have been recorded by the server or client. All files requested get checked out.

Comment: Do you have any anitvirus or indexing software installed on server or clients? Such long delays may happen if any other application (antivirus or other index) opens file blocking reading it.

Comment: Other question: how is your Subversion configured? Also I recommend you to check network drivers and disable TCP/IP checksum offloading feature.